# Imported OneHotEncoder but it's not callable

Tags: scikit-learn

#Getting data ready

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
```

#Modelling

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
```

#Setup Random Seed

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
```

#Import data and drop the rows with missing labels

```
data = pd.read_csv("car_sales_extended_missing_data.csv")
data.dropna(subset=['Price'], inplace = True)
```

## Define different features in a transformer pipeline

```
categorical_features = ['Make', 'Colour']
categorical_transformer = pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value= 'missing')),
    ("onehot", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))])

door_feature = ['Doors']
door_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy = "constant", fill_value=4))])

numeric_feature = ['Odometer (KM)']
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'))
])
```

#Setup the preprocessing steps(fill missing values, then convert to numbers)

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer( 
               transformers=[
                   ("cat", categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
                   ("door", door_transformer,door_feature),
                   ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_feature)
               ])

#Creating a preprocessing and modelling pipeline

model = Pipeline(steps= [("preprocessor", preprocessor),
                        ("model", RandomForestRegressor())])
```

#Split data

```
x = data.drop("Price", axis = 1)
y = data["Price"]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size= 0.2)
```

#Fit and score

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
model.score(x_test, y_test)
```

```
TypeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-6e69f4fb2bfa> in <module>
     26 categorical_transformer = pipeline(steps=[
     27     ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value= 'missing')),
---> 28     ("onehot", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))])
     29 
     30 door_feature = ['Doors']

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hi! I think you made a typo. You wrote the first letter of `pipeline` with no capital letter. You have to use: `Pipeline` as you did for example with "door_transformer".

Comment: Thank you! this was so silly and frustrating at the same time. Had a good laugh.